# Can I use selectors to control this checkbox hack across divs?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a very basic checkbox hack I'm using for selecting different items. 
 It does exactly what I want it to do: namely, clicking on the label allows me to select the corresponding figure:

```css
input[type="checkbox"] { display:none; }

.wrap { width: 50%; }
.wrap label { display: inline-block;}

.checker {background: red; padding: 50px;}
.checker figure { margin: 10px; display: inline-block; position: relative;}

.wrap input { display: none; }
.wrap input:checked ~ .checker { display: none; }

.wrap input:checked + label { color: blue; }

.wrap #check1cont:checked ~ .check1 {display: inline-block;}
.wrap #check2cont:checked ~ .check2 {display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  

 <input type="checkbox" name="cont" id="check1cont">
 <label class="check1cont" for="check1cont">Check 1</label>

 <input type="checkbox" name="controllers" id="check2cont">
 <label class="check2cont" for="check2cont">Check 2</label>



<figure class="checker check1">CHECK 1</figure>

<figure class="checker check2">CHECK 2</figure>
  
</div>
```

But I want the controllers/labels to be aligned on the left side, with the figures on the right.  Ideally, I'd like to be able to do this with flex, so the labels are housed in a responsive, left-aligned div.

I've tried adding the divs with different sibling and child selectors, but I'm new to all of this, and I don't think I've gotten the right combination (or else I'm doing something else wrong, or else it's impossible).

Can anyone recommend a means of doing this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is pared down from a larger, more complex bit, so ``.checker figure`` is there more for (removed) styling than the actual checkbox mechanism. Is it detrimental?  And I've tried your suggestion, and I think I've got it working!  Thank you so, so very much.

Comment: And one more question... I've got it working beautifully, but now that I've separated the checkbox and the labels, the adjacent sibling combinator ``input:checked + label {color: blue;}`` obviously no longer does the trick, and I'm having some issue trying to style the label with the input checked.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I posted an answer, which is what I should have done immediately, but I wasn't sure what to do with the issues I mentioned and the fact that it seems to rely on iffy specificity rules. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hidden checkbox tricks works because the checkboxes themselves can be anywhere in relation to the labels. So put the checkboxes first, and the labels in a separate container following them, and you can control both the labels and the figures with the :checked state of the checkboxes.

```css
.wrap { display:flex; width:50%; vertical-align:top;}
.wrap aside {vertical-align:top;}
.wrap label {white-space:nowrap; display: block;}

.checker {background: red; padding: 50px; vertical-align:top;}
.checker {margin: 10px; display: inline-block; position: relative;}

.wrap input { display: none; }
input:checked ~ main .checker { display: none; }

#check1cont:checked ~ aside .check1cont,
#check2cont:checked ~ aside .check2cont { color: blue; }

#check1cont:checked ~ main .check1,
#check2cont:checked ~ main .check2 {display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">

  <input type="checkbox" name="cont" id="check1cont">
  <input type="checkbox" name="controllers" id="check2cont">
  
  <aside>
    <label class="check1cont" for="check1cont">Check 1</label>
    <label class="check2cont" for="check2cont">Check 2</label>
  </aside>
  
  <main>
    <figure class="checker check1">CHECK 1</figure>
    <figure class="checker check2">CHECK 2</figure>
  </main>
</div>
```

Note: as was remarked in the comments, the code is a simplification of the real code, so I had to clean up the css a bit. You probably have to un-clean it up to make it work for the real code again!

Comment: Brilliant work.  Again, thank you so, so much.  I'd spent an embarrassingly long time trying to suss this out on my own.